# iOS can write or read from image data from disk

Tags: ios, uiimage, disk

I'm trying to load images using the following method.

I first check if I already have the images on the disk, if I do then I will just get the image data from the disk and load it otherwise I will get the image from the server and write to disk so that the second time that I need the image I won't have to access the server.

The problem is it doesn't seem to write or read from the disk. Everytime that I want to load images for the second time it's still reads them from the server and the `NSLog(@"disk");` never gets called.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong if anyone has any idea?

```
-(UIImage *)imageWith:(NSString *)imageName isPreview:(BOOL)preview
{
     //imageName is something like "56.jpg"

     NSString *mainOrPreview = @"Preview";
     if (!preview) {
         mainOrPreview = @"Main";
     }

     NSString *pathSuffix = [[@"Images" stringByAppendingPathComponent:mainOrPreview] stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];
     NSString *path = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:pathSuffix];
     NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];

     if (imageData) {
         NSLog(@"disk");
     }

     if (!imageData && [self connected]) {

          imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[serverURL stringByAppendingPathComponent: pathSuffix]]];

         if (imageData) {

             [imageData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
         }

         NSLog(@"server");
     }

      return [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the directories don't exist beyond `Documents`. Therefore the attempts to  write the files are failing. It's always a good idea to use the file methods that have the `NSError` parameters so you can check the result.

You need to update only the code that actually writes the image from the server.

```
if (!imageData && [self connected]) {
    // This needs to be done in on a background thread!
    imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[serverURL stringByAppendingPathComponent: pathSuffix]]];

    if (imageData) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:[path stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];
        [imageData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
    }

    NSLog(@"server");
}
```